# Get orginal function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Is possible to get the original function "behind" a function that is a result of `.bind()`?
I want to get the `toString()` of it.

```
function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}

let baz = foo.bind();

console.log(baz.toString()); //-> function foo() { return 'bar'; } and not -> function () { [native code] }
```

Comment: I think OP means the original unbound context of `this`?

Comment: Perhaps if you provide an [mcve] of what you're trying to achieve we must understand your question better.

Comment: @ste2425 `(function foo(){ console.log('foo') }).bind({}).toString()` gives `function () { [native code] }` in chrome. So the question has merit, if I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for the heads up, [Heres](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.tostring) the spec that defines the behavior for reference. Didn't realize a bound function is considered an exotic object, makes sense though.

Comment: I guess the OP somehow want to access the BoundTargetFunction mentioned here but it is an internal property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a built in link to get from baz to foo, but you could add one:

```js
function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}

let baz = foo.bind(this);
baz.original = foo;

console.log(baz.original.toString());
```

If you wanted this to happen automatically whenever someone binds a function, you could override `Function.prototype.bind`. Not something i would recommend, but it would look something like this:

```js
// Using an IIFE to isolate realBind from eveyone else's scope
(function () {
  const realBind = Function.prototype.bind;
  Function.prototype.bind = function () {
    const result = realBind.apply(this, arguments);
    result.original = this;
    return result;
  }
}());

function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}

let baz = foo.bind(this);
console.log(baz.original.toString());
```

Comment: Assuming that this is for debugging purposes, it's a rather prohibitive solution…

Comment: You could override `function.prototype.bind` to do it automatically if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

So, after some digging around...

It does not appear that there is any way in firefox to make this work without overriding built in methods.

However in chrome the following *does* work:

```
function foo() { console.log('yo'); };
console.log(foo.bind({}).toString()); // function () { [native code] }
console.log(foo.bind({})); // f foo () { console.log('yo') }
```

So while there is no way to get the original back out with a call `.toString`, logging the function object directly to the console in chrome will yield a representation with the body of the original function.

[Here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.tostring) is a link to the relevant section of the spec for `Function.prototype.toString` courtesy of ste2425.

Comment: Not that it matters, but just as a point of interest this doesn't work in IE11 either.  Both `console.log` calls yield the same result (the first one).

Comment: Also, without programmatic access to the value it's probably somewhat pointless.

Comment: @deceze agreed, but it's the best I could come up with without overriding the builtin methods of the function prototype.

Comment: You must be able to do this just with the product of bind without know what function is behind. Sure if it's possible...

Comment: @AndréVinícius again, you can simply log the function object to the console. For instance, consider file a.js that has `function foo() {}; const bar = foo.bind({}); export default bar;` and file b.js that has `import boundFoo from './a.js'; console.log(boundFoo);` you will see the body of `foo` rather than `function () { [ native code ] }`. The problem is as deceze pointed out that you have no *programmatic* access to the string representation, you can only see it in the console.

Comment: @AndréVinícius Looking into it more its not possible because of how the spec defines the bound function. The original function is placed in an internal slot `[[BoundTargetFunction]]`. These are not available in user code but implementation specific (IE JavaScript engine). Some API's provide public getters to these, such as `new String('lol').toString()` which will return the internal slot holding the string value. Interestingly people have written proposals for private properties using dynamic internal slots.